# Using sound to encrypt any file?

Tags: windows, perl, audio

First Question: Say I have a random Base64 encoded string.  Is it possible to read each character on the string and convert each character to a frequency/sound and then same the string as a sound?

Second Question: Is it possible to do the opposite?  How would I take a sound that was created above and convert back to a base64 string?

If someone clicked no the audio encrypted file it would just be noise.

Comment: That's just encoding, though. Similar to dial tones. No encryption involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and actually being used, for example here: http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/11/beware-of-ads-that-use-inaudible-sound-to-link-your-phone-tv-tablet-and-pc/

A Perl script for this is beyond a single answer, but there are many Sound-related modules on CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=sound&mode=all You'll probably need some time for research, but it should be more or less easy to build.

Comment: Another example are POTS modem.